# Slow internet speed on WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a 105 mbps internet connection , that gives me 96 mbps speed  shown on speed test. I get this speed when I connect to a wired ethernet connection , either directly to the modem or through a router . But the problem occurs when I connect wirelessly to the wifi network of the same router. I get only 20mbps. It is linksys e2500 router , that allows simultaneous dual bands . i have tried connecting on 5Ghz network and 2.4ghz , tried all possible combinations , mixed mode , n -only , g-only etc , nothing gives me more than 20 mbps on the wifi network.
My laptop does not support 5ghz network but it support the n-standard on the 2.4 ghz. But I do have other devices in the house that support the supposedly empty 5ghz channel . I have tried everything and I never get more than 20mbps on wifi through the same router than gives 95 mbps on wired ethernet.

What can I try ?

Comment: Please list what your 802.11 modes your adapter supports specifically.  Please list which modes your router supports.  Please list the exact specifications for your router.  Without this information we cannot help you.

Comment: Get a 5ghz adapter for the laptop.  The bottleneck you are hitting is associated with 2.4 ghz, you won't get past it until you get on 5ghz

Comment: If you have an iphone download the ookla speedtest app and you can prove the bottleneck is 2.4ghz.   Run the speedtest with the phone connected to the 2.4 network, then go into settings on the phone and change to the 5.0 network and re-run the test

Comment: Since its a dual band router , I have two networks and have manually renamed both networks, one is homesweet5 and homesweet2.4 . From the routers admin page both of them are on n-mode only ( no mixed , no g-mode) , and we get the speed of 16-20mpbs even on 5ghz channel. Also there is no other network on the specific channel the router is emitting 5ghz signal ( channel 1). Also this has not to do this laptop supporting 802.11g netowrk only , first because the router is set in n-mode only , and second because we have lots of devices and none of them show more than 16-20 mbps

Comment: You need [801.11ac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#802.11ac) (not N) to get past the 23mpbs limitation.

Comment: Are u sure , because 802.11 n is supposed to work at 300mbps

Comment: I'm quite sure... "been there, done that... still have the crappy t-shirt to prove it"

Comment: I was somehow able to get 30mbps (up from 23 mbps) , after that I got a new ac router and am now getting 40 mbps ( still on 2.4ghz 802.11n) , I am waiting for my 802.11ac usb adapter , hope that will yield the complete 100 mbps.

Answer (score 2):

[How to Improve Wireless Broadband Speed](http://www.broadbandspeedchecker.co.uk/guides/improve_wireless_internet_speed.aspx) lists a number of things to look at:

- Problem with Interference from Other Users
- Problems with Windows Configuration
- Check that Your Wi-Fi is Not Being Used by Other People
- Speedup Wireless Connection by Using a Better Aerial

Each of the above has instructions as to how to check/what to fix.

See also [Why is my Wi-Fi connection speed much slower than a wired connection?](https://superuser.com/questions/334426/why-is-my-wi-fi-connection-speed-much-slower-than-a-wired-connection).

From the answer by [sblair](https://superuser.com/users/494/sblair):

> The wireless connection is the bottleneck. Even 802.11g, with theoretical bandwidth of 54Mbit/s, can typically only achieve [22Mbit/s average throughput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#802.11g) under ideal conditions. It is likely that the laptop only supports 802.11g, rather than the higher speed 802.11n.